# How to concatenate Pandas dataframes with different N rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following dataframe `df1`:

```
     A
1    123
2    456
3    765
4    987
5    456
6    234
7    111
8    222
9    677
10   55
```

and dataframe `df2`:

```
     B
1    333344
2    665577
3    889900
4    111111
```

I've tried doing this with `pd.append(ignore_index=True)` and `pd.concat(axis=1, ignore_index=True)` however the result is:

```
     A      B
1    123    333344
2    456    665577
3    765    889900
4    987    111111
5    456    NaN
6    234    NaN
7    111    NaN
8    222    NaN
9    677    NaN
10   55     NaN
```

However, my desired result would be:

```
     A      B
1    123    NaN
2    456    NaN
3    765    NaN
4    987    NaN
5    456    NaN
6    234    NaN
7    111    333344
8    222    665577
9    677    889900
10   55     111111
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do

```
df2.index = df1.index[-len(df2):]
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df
      A         B
1   123       NaN
2   456       NaN
3   765       NaN
4   987       NaN
5   456       NaN
6   234       NaN
7   111  333344.0
8   222  665577.0
9   677  889900.0
10   55  111111.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `reindex` and `shift`

```
n = len(df1) - len(df2)
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2.reindex(df1.index).shift(n)], axis=1)

Out[135]:
      A         B
1   123       NaN
2   456       NaN
3   765       NaN
4   987       NaN
5   456       NaN
6   234       NaN
7   111  333344.0
8   222  665577.0
9   677  889900.0
10   55  111111.0
```